How to calculate transformer iron core losses?
For a 3 phase, 60 Hz, 6600/690 V, star/delta transformer

Rating is 2500 kVA

At full load unity power factor it has an efficiency of 97%.

Maximum efficiency occurs at 2/3 of the full load


How to calculate the iron core losses using only this information?
I am studying this remote distance and my college is offering no assistance at all, I've already tried asking for help and they don't get back to me.
As for my attempts-
I know under the 1st condition-
97% efficiency, the output power will be 2425 kVA, so the losses (combined iron core and copper) are equal to 75 kVA.
2nd condition -
Max efficiency, is unknown, but iron losses will be equal to copper losses?
Input power will be 1667 kVA and outlet power is unknown as max efficiency % is unknown.
If I try to use formula for max efficiency = full load kVA × sqrt(Iron loss/copper loss) and then sub in Iron+copper losses=75
I get a ridiculous equation to the third order which is too complicated to solve for the allocated marks for the question.
Basically I have no idea how to solve it.

What assumptions can you made at zero load?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Wouldn't full-load be what the transformer is capable of putting out 2500kVA, like a motor?  Input would be larger to deal with losses.  Fe loss is constant for both. Cu loss would (2/3)² full-load Cu loss.

full load the input is 2500kVA,

At zero load there will still be some zero load current, but I don't know how I would calculate from the above condition and it still wouldn't help find the core or copper losses?

If you ignore the magnitizing current, you have all the core losses but no copper losses at zero load.

Did the question state that any load was balanced and that the star input had a neutral?

Doesn't state, so would assume the load is balanced and neutral wire shouldn't matter.

Rating is 2500 kVA implies the rated output is 2500 kVA.  It does not imply full load the input is 2500kVA.

This is more a math question than an electrical question.
\$P_{Loss} = P_{Fe} + (load)^2 P_{Cu}\$
At full-load, you have unity power factor.
\$P_{out} = S_{out} pf = 2,500kVA * 1 = 2,500kW\$
\$P_{in} = \frac {P_{out}}{η} = \frac {2,500kW}{0.97} = 2,577.3kW\$
\$P_{Loss} = P_{Fe} + (1)^2 P_{Cu} = P_{Fe} + P_{Cu} = 77.3kW \ \ \ ① \$
You are not given much on second load, but it is not needed.  You have the key.  Iron losses = Copper losses.
Primary and secondary currents will be 2/3 of full-load currents.  Losses are proportional to \$ I_1^2 R_1+I_2^2 R_2\$.  I believe this is the component you are missing.
\$ P_{Fe} = (2/3)^2 P_{Cu} \ \ \ ② \$

I don't think the input can be higher than the rating for the transformer. But the 2nd part relating the ratio of load to the ratio of loss seems promising, thanks

I only put the first part in because I believe you are wrong.  We care about what we are driving, not what the input is.

(@Branathon2 don't think the input can be higher than the rating for the transformer Machines (transformer being an electrical one) are built for effect, for output power. They are specified/rated that way.)
